# Reading large file and creating a dictionary using multiprocessing? (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, large-files

I have a large file ( >= 1GB) that I'm trying to read and then upload the contents into a dictionary. With just a simple code that reads one line at a time, it's taking about 8 minutes to just read the file and populate the dictionary. The code snippet that I'm using is below:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        toks = line.rstrip().split()
        id1 = toks[0]
        id2 = toks[1]
        start = int(toks[4])
        end = int(toks[5])

        if id1 not in my_dict:
            my_dict[id1] = [[start, end]]
        else:
            if [start, end] not in my_dict[id1]:
                my_dict[id1].append([start,end])

       if id2 not in my_dict:
            my_dict[id2] = [[start, end]]
        else:
            if [start, end] not in my_dict[id2]:
                my_dict[id2].append([start,end])
```

Now, just running this block of code alone is taking a long time and I'm wondering if I can speed up this process using multiprocessing may be ? I've looked into some material that are close to what I want to do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965308/python-multiprocessing-reading-a-large-file-and-updating-an-imported-dictionary) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412099/python-huge-file-reading) and many others. But, given I'm very new to this, I'm struggling to even decide if multiprocessing is the right way to go. Also, in most of the multiprocessing-related resources available, they don't explain how we update the dictionary. I think I read somewhere that sharing the same dictionary is a bad idea. I wish I could be more specific with my question and hopefully won't get flagged as not suitable for SO but I just want to speed up this process of building the dictionary.

**EDIT**

After the suggestions made by @juanpa.arrivillaga , my code looks like :

```
import collections

my_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        toks = line.rstrip().split()
        id1 = toks[0]
        id2 = toks[1]
        start = int(toks[4])
        end = int(toks[5])

        my_dict[id1].add((start,end))
        my_dict[id2].add((start,end))
```

This reduced my time to about ~21 seconds when run on a file of size ~500MB with 11mil lines.

Comment: Use sets, not lists.

Comment: I understand that it would make me avoid checking if the range already exists in the dictionary but would it substantially improve the speed of populating the dictionary ? the file usually has about 30mil lines.

Comment: That check is the slow part, so yes.

Comment: " I'm wondering if I can speed up this process using multiprocessing may be ?" You should always consider your algorithm before even attempting to consider multiprocessing. As stated above, you are inefficiently doing a membership test on lists. Fix that first

Comment: @CodeDifferent **absolutely not**. In Python, `.append` is an amoratized constant time operation. `.append`ing in a loop is idiomatic and very fast. The problem is the membership test.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the membership that was the bottleneck. I tried it on a file about 500MB with 11mil lines and before it took about 4 minutes and now it's down to 26 seconds.

Comment: still seems slow, honestly. What exactly are you doing now? There are various micro-optimizations you could do at this point if that is fixed. What sort of hard disk do you have? SSD?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm exactly running the above code and nothing else. There are plenty other things I have yet to do after i create the dictionary but for now, i'm just trying to speed up portions of my code. My computer's configuration is 8 cores, 1TB HDD , 16GB RAM. I changed the list of list to list of set. What other micro-optimzations would you propose?

Comment: This looks like a good map-reduce problem. Here is a simple python example that may apply almost directly. ( https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html )

Comment: @prameshshakya Sounds like you're still doing it wrong. Shouldn't be list of set but set of tuple.

Comment: @prameshshakya That doesn't sound right. You don't want a list of sets, then you are *still doing the membership test on a list*. **How exactly** are you handling the sets? Note, you can use a `import collections; my_dict = defaultdict(set)` and that should be as speedy as possible, then you don't need to do the check, and your loop body simply becomes `my_dict[id1].add((start, end)); my_dict[id2].add((start, end))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Even after I made the changes as you said, I'm still getting around 21 seconds.

Comment: Again, **please post your code as it currently exists**. In any case, if you are using an HDD, it may I/O bottleneck

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga apologies, i've edited the question to include the edited code. Is there anyway to improve the I/O bottleneck from a software standpoint ?

Comment: @prameshshakya unlikely, but maybe someone has a suggestion. And if it is all in one large file it will not be amenable to multiprocessing.

Comment: I would suggest putting everything in a function. Code in the global namespace is going to be slowed down by global lookups. That is one obvious micro-optimization

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, i already did that. If someone else is interested. Here's the link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga With `a = [str(i) for i in range(11000000)]` it takes my decent laptop about 2 seconds to do just `[int(i) for s in a]`. So sounds reasonable now.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yeah, you are right. I think the IO is what is dominating the runtime at this point.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Reading one large file should be fast (no matter SSD or HDD). Plus with 16 GB RAM, their 500 MB file might stay in cache between their attempts. I think it's mostly that all those operations take time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , do you think changing the lines where i'm converting string to int could be done in a fashion where map() can be used which would speed it up?

Comment: @prameshshakya no. That isn't going to speed anything up appreciably, unless you were doing one giant conversion. Even then, I would only expect a marginal improvement.

Comment: Thank you all of you guys. I guess that's all the performance I can squeeze out of it. Will keep my eyes open to any else's suggestions.

Comment: You could remove the `rstrip()`. The `split()` discards that whitespace anyway.